# Command line to create a PDF document from a batch of images

Tags: bash, homebrew, pdf, preview, sips

How to create a PDF document from a batch of images ?

===

Belowis what I tried before posting this question:

The **ImageMagick** way, but the PDF document generated is too big:

```
convert *.ppm book.pdf
```

The **Preview** tool way, the created document is much smaller but it creates margins.

The **sips** way, not working for some reason:

```
sips -s format pdf *.ppm --out 'book.pdf' 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

There also **img2pdf** which looks good but I couldn't install it on mac (it's not in brew's list of packages).

Comment: Automator has a "create PDF from images" action (and one to compress images within PDFs).

Comment: Have you considered converting the .ppm files to jpegs or something similar then working with regular image files?

Comment: sips may not work on ppm files.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's own Automator action uses a python script to access Core Graphics. It works, but it's slow. 
[Here's a better python script](https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite) which uses Apple's newer PDFKit framework.

You can use this from the Terminal with filenames as arguments, or you can stick it in an Automator Run Shell Script Action.

No installations or dependencies.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
#
# IMAGE2PDF v.2.0 : Convert image files to one PDF.
# by Ben Byram-Wigfield 

import sys, os
import Quartz as Quartz
from LaunchServices import kUTTypePDF
from CoreFoundation import NSImage

def getFilename(filepath, basename):
    fullname = basename + ".pdf"
    i=0
    while os.path.exists(os.path.join(filepath, fullname)):
        i += 1
        fullname = basename + " %02d.pdf"%i
    return os.path.join(filepath, fullname)

def imageToPdf(argv):
    prefix = os.path.dirname(argv[0]) 
    filename = "Combined"
    pdfout = getFilename(prefix, filename)

    for index, eachFile in enumerate(argv):
        image = NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(eachFile)
        if image:
            page = Quartz.PDFPage.alloc().initWithImage_(image)
            if index == 0:
                pageData = page.dataRepresentation()
                pdf = Quartz.PDFDocument.alloc().initWithData_(pageData)
            else:
                pdf.insertPage_atIndex_(page, index)

    pdf.writeToFile_(pdfout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    imageToPdf(sys.argv[1:])
```